# 'rocket-worker-thread' panicked at 'Cannot drop a runtime in a context where blocking is not allowed'

Tags: rust, rust-tokio, rust-rocket, reqwest

I'm trying to call a downstream API and return the results as a Json object. I'm using `reqwest` which uses `tokio`:

Cargo.toml

```
[dependencies]
rocket = { version = "0.5.0-rc.1", features = ["secrets", "tls", "json"] }
reqwest = { version = "0.11", features = ["blocking", "json"] }
tokio = { version = "1", features = ["full"] }
```

main.rs

```
#[post("/teams")]
fn teams() -> Json<Vec<Team>> {
    let mut r = reqwest::blocking::get("https://example.com");
    if r.is_ok() {
        return Json(get_teams(r.unwrap().text().unwrap()));
    } else {
        return Json(Vec::new());
    }
}
```

The error I get is:

```
thread 'rocket-worker-thread' panicked at 'Cannot drop a runtime in a context where blocking is not allowed. This happens when a runtime is dropped from within an asynchronous context.'
```

Is this because I'm using a blocking call? How can I make a blocking call and simply return the results. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: why do you use blocking if you use tokio ?!?

Comment: did you solve this problem?@Nightwolf

Comment: @Dolphin yes, i posted an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what did it for me:

```
#[post("/teams")]
async fn teams() -> Json<Vec<Team>> {
    return Json(get_teams(reqwest::get("https://example.com").await.unwrap().text().await.unwrap()));
}
```

Cargo.toml

```
reqwest = { version = "0.11", features = ["blocking", "json"] }
tokio = { version = "1", features = ["full"] }
```